# very frequent update in CDN server

Tags: javascript, dynamic, counter, cdn

I have hosted a static java script in CDN server which serves its purpose well.

But there is a new requirement where a counter should be placed on the script and need to incremented during each view.

Will this be achievable in CDN server? if so please enlighten me about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not.

The definition of a CDN is a bit fuzzy by generally the features are:

**Heavily cached responses** so the script wouldn't be re-requested for each view.

**Static files** so the server couldn't do anything in response to the script being requested.

**Multiple, geographically dispersed servers** so that a nearby server can respond to the request (which breaks once they have to start coordinating shared counts of data).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform such counting on CDN server as it serves for content delivery.

However, most likely you can achieve desired result if you would **enable logging on CDN Server** and create log parser which would count how much times your script was downloaded.